# SpringBoot - Wrong profile and wrong bean chosen despite correct spring.profiles.active=local

Tags: java, spring-boot

Small question regarding an issue with Spring profiles please.

Currently, in my application.properties, I have this setup.

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

I am also sure there is no override whatsoever,

In my code, I have two beans, where I would like Spring to chose correctly depending on the current profile.

```
 @Bean(name = SESSION)
    @Profile({LOCAL, INTEGRATION})
    protected CqlSession cqlSession() {
        System.out.println("I would like to be chosen when profiles are local or integration");
        return CqlSession.builder().addContactEndPoint(new DefaultEndPoint(new InetSocketAddress(contactPoints, port))).withKeyspace(keyspace).withLocalDatacenter(datacenter).withAuthCredentials(username, passPhrase).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = SESSION)
    protected CqlSession cqlSession(Environment env, SSLFactory sslFactory) {
        System.out.println("current profile: " + Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
        System.out.println("Profile seems to be local, but yet, it chose me");
        return CqlSession.builder().addContactEndPoint(new DefaultEndPoint(new InetSocketAddress(contactPoints, port))).withKeyspace(keyspace).withLocalDatacenter(datacenter).withAuthCredentials(username, passPhrase).withSslContext(sslFactory.getSslContext()).build();
    }
```

Looking at this code snippet, I am expecting when my local profile is active, the first bean is chosen (the one without SSL).

However, on each run, this got printed.

```
current profile: [local]
Profile seems to be local, but yet, it chose me
```

Which is very strange to me, as the runtime understands the current profile is local, but yet, decide to go with the bean that is not annotated with profile local.

May I know what is the issue, and how to make it pick the correct bean, the one with local profile please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Profile` annotation [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

> If the @Profile annotation is omitted, registration will occur regardless of which (if any) profiles are active. NOTE: With @Profile on @Bean methods, a special scenario may apply: In the case of overloaded @Bean methods of the same Java method name (analogous to constructor overloading), an @Profile condition needs to be consistently declared on all overloaded methods. If the conditions are inconsistent, only the condition on the first declaration among the overloaded methods will matter. @Profile can therefore not be used to select an overloaded method with a particular argument signature over another; resolution between all factory methods for the same bean follows Spring's constructor resolution algorithm at creation time. Use distinct Java method names pointing to the same bean name if you'd like to define alternative beans with different profile conditions; see ProfileDatabaseConfig in @Configuration's javadoc.

I think that means your first bean can be registered event though it has no profile annotation. So spring will decide at creation time. I think the answer is probably to annotate the ssl enabled bean with `@Profile("!local")` and possibly change the bean method name.